# Why are developers so precious about releasing APIs when you can implement versioning?

Tags: api, architecture, versioning, asp.net-web-api

When ever I hear discussions on releasing version 1 APIs it's always accompanied by this genereal idea:

> We can't release our API yet because we have to get it right the first time.

Here's a recent example by [Vic Gundotra](https://plus.google.com/107117483540235115863/posts/EstNjiL2uon), but there re numerous others including Stackoverflow itself, back in the day before the API was released.

What I don't understand is, why does the first version have to be so "right"? With APIs you can implement versioning and good documentation, and if you do that well, which isn't that hard to do, why be so precious about the version 1 API?

From version to version, because it's versioned, the API can change dramatically without any breaking changes, since the old version is still supported. I was wondering why the big issue about releasing APIs..?

Comment: Your logic is kind of odd... Isn't it best to get it right the first time and after that build on to it and make it better?

Comment: "... since the old version is still supported" - maintaining old versions is a huge burden.

Comment: @nile: Not really. How can you define "getting it right". Seems too "waterfall" to me. If you implement ideas of Agile and even Lean development, how can you know it's right. The same way the first version of your software isn't "right". you know it's gonna change in time.

Comment: well, now I think we're just dealing with words. the developers want to make the first run a good one, which can take time.

Comment: @nile: thanks nile. Maybe, I guess I'm trying to look at how APIs fit within the notion of lean development, just put this here to get other people's views. I think Mat for example has a great point about how maintaining old versions is a burden indeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> From version to version, because it's versioned, the API can change dramatically without any breaking changes, since the old version is still supported.

That means two things:

- Maintaining multiple versions of an API. Even if you only support "the last 3 versions" that's still a burden. In particular, if you expose a feature you want to *remove* later on, it means you can't do any of the clean-up which would be available as part of the removal until N more versions have come and gone. Consider any ramifications on stored data that may come about due to significant changes in the API - migrating storage representations when they're used by multiple systems, updated on different release schedules, is a real pain. (Yes, there's a difference between implementation and API - but changes in API often end up meaning changes all the way through the stack.)
- Eventually irritating a lot of developers. Even if you give plenty of warning, people *will* get annoyed if they have to do significant rewrites because version 1.0 was rubbish and when 1.4 comes out, 1.0 will be removed.

Designing an API correctly is a tricky business. Yes, there's a balance to be struck between pragmatism and perfectionism - but it's not nearly as simple as you're making it out to be.

I'd also point out that there's a pretty big maintenance difference between (say) an open source project with 10 users putting something out quickly then changing it, and a company like Google or Microsoft doing so for a global developer community. There's even a big difference between an internal API at a big company (where you can't easily fix the whole codebase) and an internal API at a small company where you get to change the world whenever you want.

I have some sympathy for the astonishment about making such a big deal about it - but that suggests you haven't experienced the pain that shifting an API can mean. You might be equally astonished - or even more so - at just how hard it can be to make fundamental changes once a bad decision has escaped into the world.

(Disclaimer: I work for Google, but not in the G+ area. The opinions in this answer are my own, and don't represent Google.)

Comment: +1 hey Jon, thanks for your input! I know my question seems loaded, but it is a question and these answers are incredibly valuable. However, I'm still left wanting. For example, your first point. So say you do spend ages trying to perfect your API. Eventually your underlying system may have to change, and then what? What was the point of thinking about the metaphors for you API for so long, when you've hit the same problem anyway. Why not just release an API that target your system the way it is now, and worry about the changes later, it's gonna happen any way no?

Comment: @andy: New versions of the .NET framework generally *add* new features, but rarely do they break existing APIs. I doubt developers would be as excited to learn that their existing apps won't run on a new version of the framework.

Comment: @andy: casablanca's point is exactly the important one. A good API will still need to change over time - but everything which is there needs to *stay* there unless you really want to irritate people. Additionally, for things like interfaces with others will implement, you can't even add to that, or you'll break existing implementations. Some APIs and frameworks don't need to strive for backward compatibility, but those that do realy need to be thought through carefully.

Comment: @JonSkeet hey Jon, thanks again. I get what you guys are saying, but it doesn't really address that whole notion of "you're bound to your initial API". Software is a fluid thing, and we always know that it will change. I'm just wondering why APIs are treated differently...?

Comment: @andy: It's because if I decide to make a change, it affects you and your investment in my API. Customers don't tend to take kindly to vendors breaking their code.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bit hard to answer. But let me try. You do your programmming, but did you get it mostly right the first time?

Well my experience is that I start with some method and indeed it grows. After the tests are green I look at it and found it not good enough. I'm adding other methods I'm trying to "clean" it.

Now a API for a larger software package, is not that "small" at all. And I bet you do not even get near something you find "good" enough, right from the start. However if you release an API you'r bound to it. You will  not make many friends breaking APIS as you go. So if you are somewhat serious about your code you will support the different versions.

I suggest to have  a look into the history of GTK. there is GTK 1.2.x and things  beyond 2. We once wrote software according to GTK 1.2 and were not "happy" as 2 was coming out not compatible with 1.2. And so the software still sticks in 1.2.x of GTK...

So not the usual way is not that  you have still an olde API running but have it broken. And therefor, programmers are not that happy to realease an API very early (IMHO)

Comment: +1 thanks Friedrich... I guess I just don't buy the idea of being "bound" to it. You just support the last "n" versions, where "n" is quite a small number like 2 or 3. Also an API change is really only when the interface changes, not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe ask for an extendable API, eg:

APIclass::anAPIcall(Xclass Xparam, Yclass Yparam, void *userData, void *extensions);

.. where 'extensions' is passed as Null in V1.0.

You could agree with the vendor that the functionality provided by V1.0 will not be supported, (but will continue to be provided), in later releases.